Nuxt3 site deployed to cloudflare pages produces errors when calling server endpoint
When I run in my dev environment routes defined in the /server folder works as expected and the individual pages in my nuxt site can call the api like:
const posts: Post[] = (await useFetch(() => '/api/post')).data.value 

but when I deploy to cloudflare pages, even as the build is successful, all calls to the server api results in 404 errors.
This worked at one point but Im not sure if Cloudflare or Nuxt changed something.
Im running the latest version of Nuxt and nodejs in both environments.
Any pointers or help would be greatly appriciated.
